# Android Studio - TextView not showing in design view layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am brand new to trying out an android app. I started to follow the online tutorial (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui), but getting a bit frustrated at adding a new TextView, as according to the tutorial, it should show in design view, and let me move it around. It is invisible to me in design view though, and I can only see it by running an emulation. Please can someone let me know if I am doing something wrong? or something the tutorial does not tell you? or is this just a bug?

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

Thank you in advance for any advice you can offer.

Comment: post your gradle file

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply prashant17. Please can you let me know which one? there are several .gradle files :) like I said, I am very much a complete novice here!

Comment: Your app gradle. Also click on red exclamation mark visible in screen shot for more details about error

Comment: Restart your Android studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bug in latest sdk 28 ,

Change the `compileSdkVersion  27`

`targetSdkVersion 27`

and

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

**Update:**

This is said to fix problem but I did not test it yet

In styles.xml change the parent theme for your app to `Base.Theme.AppCompat` instead of `Theme.AppCompat`

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue too, this is a issue from the latest `support.appCompact`.

Inside `gradle` dependencies if your using,

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

change to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

This will fix the issue

Answer (score 2):

You see it in the component tree so, if you want to modify or delete it, you can do that from there.

Comment: Anyway, I think it's an Android Studo bug

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I could see the settings to play with in the attributes window, but it was just upsetting me I could not use design view like the tutorial was specifying :)

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, check to see **if your dependencies match your SDK level**. To check this, go to your app.gradle file and check every highlighted statement for version conflicts.

If this doesn't work, your next debugging step should be to **restart your Android studio**. Since the view shows in your component tree (and in your emulator), it ought to show in your preview. Previews in android studio lag sometimes due to various reasons (mostly machine related).

If it still doesn't show up after restarting, the problem might be a larger scale IDE issue and you should consider updating your question accordingly.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Found an easier way than adding code or changing SDK. It is just hidden and you have to show it by checking the "Show layout Decorations"

Hope it helps.

P.S. it also solves the hidden toolbar problem [Picture of where to find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l50JJ.png)