# preview in android studio is blank and showing only mobile frame

Tags: android, android-studio, preview

I have tried clean build and restart the android studio but its not working. Any solution please!!
the preview is not showing any change.

[image: as the image shows that no change is observed in the picture]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51591251/android-studio-textview-not-showing-in-design-view-layout/51591502#51591502

Comment: post your gradle file and style file.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the error by clicking that Red error symbol on right side upper corner in preview screen and share the error message here.

Just try to change the value inside Style.xml file from `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` to `parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`. See if it works or not or share your error.

Thanks

Comment: "Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error."
This is the error message that is shown in the screen

Comment: Try to change Style.xml file as above and see if it works.

Comment: Oh it worked 

166
down vote
×
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.
found it on this site, it works on me. Modify /res/values/styles.xml from:

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
to:

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>

Answer (score 0):

Change your Dependencies version to alpha1

> Like

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
```