# Android Layout Unable to see app Preview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am not able to see the preview in the Android layout like the `toolbar` or the `ActionBar`. Below is the screenshot of the app:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51591502/6478047

Comment: Click the red exclamation mark in the top right corner - what does the error say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you are using SDK 28 as SDK 28 has a bug. Change

```
compileSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 28
```

to

```
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
```

and use this in `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

If you're not using SDK 28, you can try `Build -> Clean Project` or restart Android Studio.