# Android Studio's review layout did not show text. Why this happen?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

[image]

This problem happen after android studio suddenly close itself. I feel relieve when i see the interface output can show it's text but, it annoy me when i try to codes the interface and there is no text shown there. How can i solve this problem and what make this problem occur?

Comment: Try invalidate cache and restart. Might work.

Comment: @KalanaChinthaka still not work.

Comment: Are you using android sdk 28?

Comment: yes, i using sdk 28.

Comment: is it because of the API preview is 30 that the text didnt come out?

Comment: I had the same issue once. It is a bug in the SDK 28 I guess. Change the compile sdk version and the target sdk versions of your gradles builds to 27 if it is OK with you.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but still not working. I just realize that it happen on this page only. Then i open another copy of this program. Only that page did.nt show text. Maybe i' should start from scratch.

Comment: Change your appcompat dependencies to implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' as well. I found a sample problem here also. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51591251/13685592

Answer (score 0):

I already solve this problem by use the new render layout. I kind a hesitate to use it at first because i have face this problem before and it is also render problem. No matter how many time i change my codes according to suggestion and change the render layout. Still nothing works. I need start from scratch because i can't find the solution. But this time it's work.